# Send PHPMailer HTML email with variables in PHP

Tags: php, html, email, variables, phpmailer

Ok, i have this email that i wanna send by form with post method with PHPMailer. I wanna put the content of four variables inside the body of the message, but every time i recieve the email empty. The place of the variables is empty. What is wrong with my code?

```
                            <?php
            $nome      = $_POST['nome'];
            $telefone  = $_POST['fone'];
            $email     = $_POST['email'];
            $mensagem  = $_POST['mensagem'];

            require("class.phpmailer.php");
            require('class.smtp.php');

            $mail = new PHPMailer();

            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.studiobm.com.br';
            //$mail->Host = "localhost"; 
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
            $mail->Port       = 587;   
            $mail->Username   = "*******"; 
            $mail->Password   = "*******";   

            $mail->From = "contato@studiobm.com.br"; 
            $mail->Sender = "contato@studiobm.com.br";
            $mail->FromName = "Bruno Marques"; 

            $mail->AddAddress('moafuhr@gmail.com', 'Bruno Marques');


            $mail->Subject  = "Bruno Marques Site"; 
            $mail->Body =   '<html><body style="margin:auto;width:599px;">
            <img src="http://www.studiobrunomarques.com.br/site/wp-content/themes/bm/bannercontato.png" />
            <table width="599" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="12" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:150%;background:#CCCCCC;">
            <tr style="background:#e2e2e2;"><td>Nome:</td><td>'.$nome.'</td></tr>
            <tr><td>E-mail:</td><td>'.$email.'</td></tr>
            <tr style="background:#e2e2e2;"><td>Telefone:</td><td>'.$telefone.'</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Mensagem:</td><td>'.$mensagem.'</td></tr>
            </table>
            </body></html>
            ';

            $mail->IsHTML(true); 

            $enviado = $mail->Send();

            $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
            $mail->ClearAttachments();

            if ($enviado) {
            echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
            } else {
            echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.

            ";
            echo "Informações do erro: 
            " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: basic debugging: do you see your data in `var_dump($_POST)` output? Did you check if `$nome` and the like actually contain anything?

Comment: The e-mail is empty even if I declare a value to the variables, instead of take the post value.

Comment: You should be using `->MsgHTML('<html>...')`, not ->Body.

Comment: MsgHTML is optional - setting Body directly is quite legitimate and gives you more control.

Comment: i am aware this is an older post, but i am curious if a solution was ever found?  it would be a great reference if there was.